# How to represent a dative verb in first order logic?

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar, logic, lambda-calculus

I understand that the representation of an intransitive verb, `V` in lambda calculus would be `lambda x. V(x)`, where `x` is the subject.

How do I represent an intransitive verb followed by a prepositional phrase? For example, *I agree with you.*

One solution is to create a transitive verb `agree_with` and use the expression `lambda x y. agree_with(x,y)`.

Is there a first order representation that doesn't mix the concepts of transitivity and intransitivity?

Comment: On Davidson's view, every verb has an event as its first argument. That is, you have agree(e, subj) and the preposition phrase would be with(e, you). In subatomic semantics there'd be agree(e) & actor(I, e).

Comment: If you ask "is there another way?" then the answer will inevitably be yes. Such a question is ultimately opinion based.

Comment: @curiousdannii I edited my post to make the wording less subjective

Comment: @mac389 You might need to justify calling *agree* an intransitive verb. It seems like a straightforward transitive verb to me. Its internal argument may be left out when context makes it clear, but it's still fundamentally transitive, I think.

Comment: I never thought of it that way. What would the internal argument be?

Comment: "you", "your point", "what you are saying", "your opponent's arguments". *agree with* can be analysed as a [bipartite verb](http://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/000435/current.pdf).

Comment: @mac389 In first-order logic you could represent a verb with a predicate that takes all possible modifiers as arguments. A less obviously wrong approach is to say that "agree" is transitive (clearly it's not as it takes no direct object). In a few frameworks whatever is obligatory is taken to be part of the verb's predicate. If you for some reason do now want to use Parsons' subatomic semantics, then the best way is to adopt the so-called proto-roles (actants). Then a transitive verb would have 2 arguments and an intransitive verb like "agree" would have one argument and facultative modifiers.

Comment: So _agree with_ would be the transitive form of _agree_, though the DO could be either the propositions agreed with or the persons agreed with, or both, with other prepositions.

Answer (score 1):

How to represent "I agree with you"?  Try this: let *p* = "I agree with you", then the representation is *p*.

I imagine you don't find that answer very enlightening, but what is wrong with it?  My representation satisfies all the logical properties you said you were interested in.  That's because you didn't say what logical properties you wanted the representation to have, so any representation will do as well as another.  I give you the simplest one that occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

The following NLTK feature-based context-free grammar will parse the sentence "X agrees with Y" into `agree(X,Y)`.

```
 S[NUM=?n,SEM=<?np(?vp)>] -> NP[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] VP[NUM=?n,SEM=?vp] 
 NP[NUM=?n,SEM=?np] -> N[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] 
 VP[NUM=?n,SEM=<?np(?vp)>] -> BV[NUM=?n, SEM=?vp] PP[SEM=?np]
 BV[NUM=sg,SEM=<\y x.agree(x,y)>] -> 'agree'

 PP[SEM=?np] -> Prep N[SEM=?np]

 N[NUM=sg, SEM=<\P.P(X)>] -> 'X'
 N[NUM=sg, SEM=<\P.P(Y)>] -> 'Y'

 Prep -> 'with'
```

This representation oversimplifies important aspects.

- It treats the object of any prepositional phrase as the object of the verb.
- It skirts the complexity of a bipartite verb by omitting the second verb phrase.

It will, accordingly, fail on sentences such as "I agree with you on something." or, even worse "I agree on something with you."

Comment: The PP should be adjoined to the VP.

Comment: I agree. How would I represent that in lambda calculus?

Comment: That might be a problem. But since agree isn't transitive the predicate should be unary and the formula should be a conjunction. You could then analyze "I agree with you on something" which would consist of three conjuncts.

Comment: The question, answer, and exchange in general are noteworthy for me. The question produces a simple sentence "I agree with you". It asks a simple question about how lambda-calculus captures the meaning. The answer and the exchange demonstrate, however, that lambda-calculus may have difficulty with the example. For me this casts doubt on the value of the lambda-calculus as applied to natural language in general. What good is it if it cannot deal with such a simple example?

Comment: @TimOsborne The use of lambda calculus is problematic here because mac389 explicitly asked for a representation in first-order logic. In a higher-order logic, there'd be no problem (I prefer first-order logic with explicit events, though). The lambda calculus isn't part of formal logic, it's an independent component and somewhat similar to linear logic. Its main disadvantage is that it isn't monotonic.

Comment: @Atamiri, I cannot understand your comments. Your using a lot of terminology that I think is probably not accessible to many in this forum. Consider spelling things out a little more, so that your comments are more accessible. Here's my beef with the lambda-calculus: most versions that I've encountered seem to be compatible with binary branching syntactic structures only. If that is so, then the lambda-calculus is not a good tool for capturing the syntax-semantic interface, since I think there's lots of evidence supporting relatively flat syntactic structures. Comments?

Comment: @Atarmi I understand that lambda calculus is a way to represent FOL, but it isn't FOL nor can it represent only FOL. Python's implementation of lambda calculus only extends to FOL AFAIK, reflecting that a very common use of lambda calculus, at least for computational people, is to represent FOL. I'm editing my question to be explicit about that difference.

Comment: @mac389 This isn't completely true. Lambda calculus can work with any logic that has variables and it's often used to build up expressions in higher-order logic. I'm afraid it can't be explained in a few words but if there's a follow-up question (about the relationship between lambda calculus and logical form) I'll write a detailed answer.

Comment: @TimOsborne Semantics is part of logic, hence the terminology. I suggest you ask a new question so I can write a longer answer. Briefly: Lambda calculus can be viewed as "binary branching" and it's indeed a bit unwieldy if you use it for building up logical forms. In monotonic parsers (DG;) it's not very practical. Let's continue the discussion elsewhere.

Comment: @Atamiri here's the follow-up question: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11593/what-is-the-relationship-between-lambda-calculus-and-logical-form