# Languages with an aspectual split indicating whether a new "event" is introduced

Tags: aspect

I've seen articles covering semantics-related topics that present a formalism where every finite verb receives an event argument. [This comment](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11578/how-to-represent-a-dative-verb-in-first-order-logic#comment29388_11578) on a question on this site *briefly* describes what an event argument is.

I think you might be able to use this event machinery to explain why finite verbs in various sentences receive perfective or imperfective aspect. The idea being that the *perfective* introduces a new event and the *imperfective* does not. This isn't my idea. I'm cobbling together some half-remembered ideas presented in a few papers I read a long time ago, I'll try to find a source. I suspect the real distinction is more complicated ... and the choice of aspectual marking depends on more than whether the event in question is a new discourse participant or not.

That being said, I wonder if there's a language with an aspect distinction that's close-to-ideal from the perspective of events and could be used to support a theory of events as verb arguments in the first place.

I'm wondering if there are any languages with a 2-way aspectual distinction that aligns particularly well with the "am I introducing a new event?" test.

Comment: "Newness" of information really has nothing to do with aspect. Shouldn't you be looking at topic/focus instead?

Comment: German flavouring particles like *ja*, *doch* and *schon* come to mind.